# Can the witch hunter fire with his melee weapon

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

In the game you have different classes, each of the classes has a melee weapon and a ranged weapon. Now the Witch hunter class starts off with a rapier as melee and pistols as ranged.

If you block with the rapier it also shows that he is holding a pistol, also his melee weapon has a bullet counter which the rest of the melee weapons don't have.

Now the question is is it possible to fire the pistol while using the rapier as melee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, special weapon 1 key, you can rebind it.